# Is there any way to change version of plugin in comment automatically

Tags: php, wordpress, version, comments, wordpress-plugin-creation

```
/**
 * CART-DISCOUNT
 *
 * @package           CART-DISCOUNT
 * @author            Nymul Islam Moon
 * @copyright         2023 Nymul Islam
 * @license           GPL-2.0-or-later
 *
 * @wordpress-plugin
 *
 * Version:           1.0.0
**/

$version = '1.0.0';
```

Here I wanted to use the version variable in the version comment that will automatically change in my code. Is there any way to do that?

I know that there is no way to add variable in comment but for just to make sure I have asked the question.

Comment: You cannot directly use a variable inside a comment block. Just in case you can concatenate it into string so it looks like ```..Version: " . $version . " **/";```

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth you can *read* the contents of the standardized plugin comment block with [get_plugin_data( $file, false, false );](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_plugin_data/)

You might be able to go from there to *displaying* an altered version number. But as you mentioned, to update that version in the plugin would require *writing* the plugin code file. That's not a great idea in a production web site, as it might be exploitable by a cybercreep.